# Function in C using structures to calculate area and perimeter of a trapezoid (one test not passing)?

Tags: c, structure

The structures are given:

```
struct Point {
    double x, y;
};
struct Trapezoid {
    struct Point A,B,C,D;
};
```

I need to write a trapezoids function that receives an array of type struct Trapezoid, the size of the array n, and two empty arrays of type double that we assume are large enough to hold all the required elements. The perimeter of the received trapezoids should be entered in the array given as the third parameter, and their area as the fourth parameter. I have written code that works, but one case doesn't.

```
  #include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

struct Point {
    double x;
    double y;
};

struct Trapezoid {
    struct Point A, B, C, D;
};

double distance(struct Point p1, struct Point p2) {
    double dx = p2.x - p1.x;
    double dy = p2.y - p1.y;
    return sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
}

void trapezoids(struct Trapezoid trapezoids[], int n, double perimeters[], double areas[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        double side1 = distance(trapezoids[i].A, trapezoids[i].B);
        double side2 = distance(trapezoids[i].B, trapezoids[i].C);
        double side3 = distance(trapezoids[i].C, trapezoids[i].D);
        double side4 = distance(trapezoids[i].D, trapezoids[i].A);

        perimeters[i] = side1 + side2 + side3 + side4;

        double baseAvg = (side1 + side3) / 2;
        double height = distance(trapezoids[i].B, trapezoids[i].D);

        double rotation_angle_rad = atan2(trapezoids[i].B.y - trapezoids[i].D.y, trapezoids[i].B.x - trapezoids[i].D.x);
        double rotation_angle_deg = rotation_angle_rad * 180 / M_PI;

        // Corrected formula for area with rotation
        areas[i] = 0.5 * (side1 + side3) * height * fabs(sin(rotation_angle_rad));
    }
}

int main() {
    struct Trapezoid array[4];
    double areas[4];
    double perimeters[4];

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("Enter coordinates for trapezoid %d (A B C D): ", i + 1);
        scanf("%lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf",
              &array[i].A.x, &array[i].A.y,
              &array[i].B.x, &array[i].B.y,
              &array[i].C.x, &array[i].C.y,
              &array[i].D.x, &array[i].D.y);
    }

    // If input doesn't match, calculate the actual output
    trapezoids(array, 4, perimeters, areas);

    // Print the results
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("%.2f ", perimeters[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The case that doesn't work:

```
Result: Wrong result
Test Code:

struct Trapezoid array[] = {
  { {-4,2}, {0.950, 6.950}, {-2.586, 7.657}, {-5.414, 4.828} }, // 45 degrees
  { {-4,2}, {-7.5, 8.062}, {-9.098, 4.830}, {-7.098, 1.366} }, // 120 degrees
  { {-4,2}, {-11, 2}, {-9, -1}, {-5, -1} }, // 180 degrees
  { {-4,2}, {-4, -5}, {-1, -3}, {-1, 1} } // 270 degrees
};
double volumes[4], surfaces[4];
int i;

trapezoids(array, 4, perimeters, areas);
for (i=0; i<4; i++)
  printf("%.2f ", surfaces[i]);

Expected output(s): 16.50 16.50 16.50 16.50
 
Your program printed: 11.67 36.83 16.50 33.00
```

Comment: Err, isn't the area of a trapezoid `h(a+b)/2`, where `h` is the height and `a` and `b` are the lengths of the parallel sides? What's all that trigonometry stuff doing in your code?

Comment: How do you determine the height, @paxdiablo, without something like trigonometry?  You'd have to determine which are the parallel sides and the distance between them, wouldn't you?

Comment: Yes, but you don't need trig for that. Choose any two opposite sides and get the shorter one. Create a scaled version of the opposite side with the same length as the shorter one. If the distances between the equivalent endpoints is the same, those two are the parallels. Otherwise, the other two are (though I'd check that anyway, using the same method). Or just work out the gradients and see if equal (keeping in mind to pre-check for infinite gradient). Having said that. distance between lines may need trig???

Comment: First, you need to do some debugging yourself before posting to Stack Overflow. Modify your program to print the individual things it calculates—the sides and the rotation angle at least—and compare them to your own manual calculations to see if any of them are wrong. Or examine them in a debugger instead of calculating them. After doing some debugging, if you still have a problem, then you could come to Stack Overflow with a specific question. Not why your whole program does not work, but why a specific part of it does not work.

Comment: Second, when you do ask a debugging question in Stack Overflow, provide a [mre]. You have shown data as an initialization of an array, but your program does not take data in that form; it reads numbers from standard input. You should provide an exact copy of input that reproduces the problem with the program shown. Further, I took the data shown, reformatted it to be suitable for the input your program apparently expects, and ran it. It print “17.77 17.77 17.77 17.77”, not “11.67 36.83 16.50 33.00”. Maybe the output you showed is for a different version of the program?…

Comment: … You need to show the actual output for the program shown in the question.

Comment: [No trigonometry is needed.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon#Area)

Comment: @paxdiablo: Re “Choose any two opposite sides… Having said that. distance between lines may need trig???”: You give two algorithms for determining which sides are parallel and then say trigonometry may be needed for determining the distance between the lines. But the program assumes it knows which lines are parallel and is only using trigonometry to determine the distance between the lines. (AB and CD are parallel in all the trapezoids shown.)

Comment: Your trigonometry is wrong. I am not sure what you are trying to calculate. You can get the cosine of the angle between sides 3 and 4 by taking the dot product of CD and DA and dividing by the lengths of those sides. Then the height is the sine of the arccosine of that angle multiplied by the length of side 4.

Comment: @Eric, I didn't want to make that assumption. But, to be honest, you don't even need trig to work out the distance. You can get a perpendicular line to the short side (using x/y swap of endpoints) and transform it so the endpoint is the same as one of the short-side endpoints. That line will intersect the long side and that's where you can calculate the height. That works both if you know the parallel lines and also if you don't but need to check. In that case you just need to check that perpendicular at the other endpoint of the short line and ensure its distance to the long one is identical.

Comment: @Eric, throwing in a single test case where BC and AD were the parallel sides is *exactly* the sort of sadistic thing I would do as an educator :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: I already linked [the very simple algorithm for calculating the area of a polygon from its vertices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon#Area). The area is half the absolute value of the sum of x[i+1]•y[i]−x[i]•y[i+1], wrapping indices for the last point. It is easier to calculate than the perimeter.

Comment: The judge output shows `surfaces[i]`, presumably the area, being printed, and the numbers it shows are the areas of the trapezoids, but your program as shown in the question prints `perimeters[i]`, which is the perimeter, not the area.

Comment: @Eric, I suspect the output with the problem is generated by something that bypasses `main` and calls `trapezoids` directly with test data. That's based on the code shown in the output and the fact no input statements are used. I could be wrong but that's how many automated classwork checkers function. Also you should probably post your nifty find of the general-polygon solution as an *answer,* it's good to know and avoids more complex math.

Comment: That's more points than is needed for a trapezoid. What if it's _not_ a trapezoid at all? Suggest `struct Quadrilateral`, which is more precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the OP test code has some confusion of variable names. I assume it should be something like this:

```
int main() {
    struct Trapezoid array[] = {
      { {-4,2}, {0.950, 6.950}, {-2.586, 7.657}, {-5.414, 4.828} }, // 45 degrees
      { {-4,2}, {-7.5, 8.062}, {-9.098, 4.830}, {-7.098, 1.366} }, // 120 degrees
      { {-4,2}, {-11, 2}, {-9, -1}, {-5, -1} }, // 180 degrees
      { {-4,2}, {-4, -5}, {-1, -3}, {-1, 1} } // 270 degrees
    };

    double areas[4];
    double perimeters[4];
    trapezoids(array, 4, perimeters, areas);

    printf("Areas: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("%.2f ", areas[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    printf("Perimeters: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("%.2f ", perimeters[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Secondly, the method for calculating the trapezoid area in the OP code is unnecessarily complicated and gives the wrong result. I have not analyzed the root cause of this since a much simpler approach exists which I recommend to use instead.

The area calculation can be done using the so-called [shoelace formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula) (250 years old math is helping us here!).

With the "determinant form" of the formula, the following helper function can be used:

```
double determinant(struct Point p1, struct Point p2)
{
    return (p1.x * p2.y - p2.x * p1.y);
}
```

With this, the areas can be calculated as follows:

```
        double det1 = determinant(trapezoids[i].A, trapezoids[i].B);
        double det2 = determinant(trapezoids[i].B, trapezoids[i].C);
        double det3 = determinant(trapezoids[i].C, trapezoids[i].D);
        double det4 = determinant(trapezoids[i].D, trapezoids[i].A);
        areas[i] = 0.5 * fabs(det1 + det2 + det3 + det4);
```

Note: calling `fabs()` can be omitted if it can be assumed that points are provided in counter-clockwise order.

With the test case of the OP, this gives the correct result:

```
Areas: 16.50 16.50 16.50 16.50 
Perimeters: 17.77 17.77 17.77 17.77
```